# Axios post method - not getting UseState data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-fullstack

Working on Full stack app, client side is giving problems mainly using axios module. The axios post method is not posting const data in the UseState from react. The server shows entry as primary ID is created but no other data is entered, it is showing as null.

This is the client side for Add Book Form:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
//import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Add = () => {
  const [bookData, setBook] = useState({
      title: '',
      author: '',
      details: '',
      price: null,
      cover: '',
      userId: 1
    })

    const [error, setError] = useState(false)

    //const navigate = useNavigate()

    const dataEntry = (event) => {
      setBook((previous) => ({...previous, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }))
    }


    const eventClick = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      try {
            const result = await axios.post('/books', bookData) //error occurs here
            console.log(result) 
            //navigate('/login')
      } catch (error) {
          setError(error.response.data)
          
      }
  
    }
    
    return (
      <div className='form'>
        <h1>Add New Book</h1>
        <form>
          <input required type={'text'} placeholder={'title'}  name={'title'}  onChange={dataEntry} />
          <input required type={'text'} placeholder={'author'} name={'author'} onChange={dataEntry} />
          <input required type={'text'} placeholder={'details'} name={'details'}  onChange={dataEntry} />
          <input required type={'number'} placeholder={'price'} name={'price'}  onChange={dataEntry} />
          <input required type={'text'} placeholder={'cover'} name={'cover'}  onChange={dataEntry} />
          <button onClick={eventClick}>ADD</button>{error && "Something went wrong!"}
        </form>
        
      </div>
    )
}

export default Add
```

I tried changing the Sequelize model structure and still getting no data entered. I've ensured my client side folder in the package.json has the 'proxy': 'http://localhost:5000/api/' route set up and still it's giving errors[image]

Comment: What's your endpoint look like?

Comment: Take a look at network tab. What url you see there? 
Also take a look at request itself, there might be some useful hints

Comment: It's connecting to the database as the id is generated in MySql workbench but the data is null

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. The index.js file in the server was missing app.use(express.json()) to read in the inputs on the request url.